# Show FloorPlan and get Location with IndoorAtlas

Tags: android, android-studio, indoor-positioning-system

Is there any resource on how to use the IndoorAtlas SDK?

I'm getting confused about how to show the floorPlan and getting current location.

Please kindly help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's very roughly how:

1) Initialize IndoorAtlas instance:

```
IndoorAtlas ia = IndoorAtlasFactory.createIndoorAtlas(context, listener, apiKey, apiSecret);
```

2) Obtain instance of FloorPlan:

```
FutureResult<FloorPlan> result = ia.fetchFloorPlan(floorPlanId);
result.setCallback(new ResultCallback<FloorPlan>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final FloorPlan result) {
                mFloorPlan = result;
                loadFloorPlanImage(result);
            }
            // handle error conditions too
}
```

3) Obtain actual image:

```
void loadFloorPlanImage(FloorPlan floorPlan) {
  BitmapFactory.Options options = createBitmapOptions(floorPlan);
  FutureResult<Bitmap> result = ia.fetchFloorPlanImage(floorPlan, options);
  result.setCallback(new ResultCallback<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final Bitmap result) {
               // now you have floor plan bitmap, do something with it
               updateImageViewInUiThread(result);
            }
            // handle error conditions too
  }
}
```

4) Start positioning:

```
ia.startPositioning(venueId, floorId, floorPlanId);
```

5) Show positions on floor plan:

```
public void onServiceUpdate(ServiceState state) {

   // get position on original floor plan image
   int i = state.getImagePoint().getI();
   int j = state.getImagePoint().getJ();

   // take into account how your floor plan image has been scaled
   // and draw position
   PointF scaledPoint = new PointF();
   Util.calculateScaledPoint((int) floorPlan.dimensions[0], (int) floorPlan.dimensions[1], i, j, mImageView, scaledPoint);

   drawNewPositionInUiThread(scaledPoint.x, scaledPoint.y);

}
```

Of course you can start positioning first and then obtain image. You could also cache image locally but like said, this was roughly how.

Util.java:

```
public class Utils {


    /**
     * Calculates scaling factor for an image with original dimensions of
     * {@code originalWidth x originalHeight} being displayed with {@code imageView}.
     *
     * The assumption with this example code is that a) layout has been already performed for
     * {@code imageView} and that {@link android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType#CENTER_INSIDE} is used.
     *
     * @param originalWidth  height of the original bitmap to be displayed using {@code imageView}
     * @param originalHeight width of the original bitmap to be displayed using {@code imageView}
     */
    public static float calculateScaleFactor(int originalWidth, int originalHeight,
                                             ImageView imageView) {

        if (imageView.getScaleType() != ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("only scale type of CENTER_INSIDE supported, was: "
                    + imageView.getScaleType());
        }

        final int availableX = imageView.getWidth()
                - (imageView.getPaddingLeft() + imageView.getPaddingRight());
        final int availableY = imageView.getHeight()
                - (imageView.getPaddingTop() + imageView.getPaddingBottom());

        if (originalWidth > availableX || originalHeight > availableY) {
            // original image would not fit without scaling
            return originalWidth > availableX
                    ? availableX / (float) originalWidth
                    : availableY / (float) originalHeight;
        } else {
            return 1f; // no scaling required
        }

    }


    /**
     * Calculates point where to draw coordinates {@code x} and {@code y} in a bitmap that's
     * original dimensions were {@code originalWidth x originalHeight} and may now be scaled down
     * as it's been displayed with {@code imageView}.
     *
     * @param originalWidth  width of the original bitmap before any scaling
     * @param originalHeight height of the original bitmap before any scaling
     * @param x              x-coordinate on original bitmap
     * @param y              y-coordinate on original bitmap
     * @param imageView      view that will be used to display bitmap
     * @param point          point where result value is to be stored
     * @see #calculateScaleFactor(int, int, ImageView)
     */
    public static void calculateScaledPoint(int originalWidth, int originalHeight,
                                            int x, int y,
                                            ImageView imageView,
                                            PointF point) {


        final float scale = calculateScaleFactor(originalWidth, originalHeight, imageView);
        final float scaledWidth = originalWidth * scale;
        final float scaledHeight = originalHeight * scale;

        // when image inside view is smaller than the view itself and image is centered (assumption)
        // there will be some empty space around the image (here offset)
        final float offsetX = Math.max(0, (imageView.getWidth() - scaledWidth) / 2);
        final float offsetY = Math.max(0, (imageView.getHeight() - scaledHeight) / 2);

        point.x = offsetX + (x * scale);
        point.y = offsetY + (y * scale);


    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Im on it. But for number 1, how you declare listener ? IndoorAtlasListener or another Listener ?

Comment: Yes, IndoorAtlasListener. Basic example of that can be found from the example app that comes with the IndoorAtlas SDK.

Comment: Perhaps i don't understand how to declare : loadFloorPlanImage,updateImageViewInUiThread,drawNewPositionInUiThread.

Could you guide me ? Thx before

Comment: loadFloorPlanImage: that was step 3) (I update answer with method signature). updateImageViewInUiThread: could be as simple as assigning bitmap to ImageView but you need to do it under main thread, e.g. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable). drawNewPositionInUiThread: here you could draw e.g. a circle on canvas at the position of your new location. I'll try to find some time to do a full example.

Comment: That was more clear. I'm sorry to forgot to mention 'createBitmapOptions'. what is inside in that method ?

Comment: Hello @LeonardFebrianto, can you please guide me waht is the value for floorplan, how to fetch image from app? I am stuck in this.

Comment: Please make it into question and give me the link. So i could asnwer in your thread.

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691539/positing-in-android-using-indooratlas please help

Comment: HI All need help to complete my code. I too used IndoorAtlas but it seems nothing was work out to me.My problem is I'm not able to show downloaded map from inddoratlas server and can't  mark user position as well.Please help to resole these issues.

Comment: can you please post the complete code to get it right. I am on the middle way, loaded and displayed a floorplan but can't go further. how to plot a point on that.