# Getting and show FloorPlan Image using IndoorAtlas

Tags: android, indoor-positioning-system

It might be duplicated with this thread : [Show FloorPlan and get Location with IndoorAtlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911753/show-floorplan-and-get-location-with-indooratlas) . But i still cannot get the floorplan image.

What i want is show floorplan image and display it into UI and show the current location. I'm using IndoorAtlas SDK.

Please help me. If possible give me your email or anything so i can chat with you if it is not simple.

Answer (score 0):

Leonard, your question can be restated as "I have a PNG image loaded into a Bitmap object, how do I display it on-screen". It's really not related at all to IndoorAtlas. Perhaps this Google tutorial is of help:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Its not what i want. i want to get image from the floorplan id. So the image load dynamically from IndoorAtlas venue.